# nginx opencart rewrite remove index.php?route

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, opencart

My site opens the home page with this link:

```
https://www.azertranss.az/index.php?route=common/home
```

But I would like to remove **index.php?route=**
How can I make URL to work with this link?

```
https://www.azertranss.az/common/home
```

I tried this:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_route_=$1 last;
```

The actual configuration is this:

```
# START  Rewrite rules

rewrite ^/sitemap.xml$ /index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap last;
rewrite ^/googlebase.xml$ /index.php?route=feed/google_base last;
rewrite ^/download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found last;
if (!-f $request_filename) {
    set $rule_3 1$rule_3;
}
if (!-d $request_filename) {
    set $rule_3 2$rule_3;
}
if ($uri !~ ".*.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)") {
    set $rule_3 3$rule_3;
}
if ($rule_3 = "321") {
    rewrite ^/([^?]*) /index.php?_route_=$1 last;
}

# END  Rewrite rules
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this as it works for me:

```
location / {    try_files $uri $uri/ @opencart; 
}
location @opencart {rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?_route_=$1 last; 
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).